# variable summaryLength not working on Hugo

Tags: hugo

I have a simple problem on Hugo. I'm trying to change the length of the summaries of posts on a list page displaying them.

If I resume the structure of my `layouts` and `content` folders, it's like this:

```
layouts
  |--- _default
    |--- baseof.html
    |--- list.html
    |--- single.html
  |--- blog
    |--- list.html
    |--- single.html

content
  |--- blog
    |--- posts
```

What I did is adding the following line code in my `config.toml`:

```
 summaryLength = 10
```

But it didn't worked. How can I do it then ?

Comment: Try putting the summaryLength=10 after the "theme=whatever" and before "params". In the config.toml files, order matters.

Comment: Thank you ! It was indeed that. If you want, you can make your comment as an answer and I'll accept it, so it will be visible for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the `summaryLength=10` after the `theme=whatever` and before `params`. The order of variables matter in the config.toml files.